# hiveserver2 not not responding on start

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am try to set up HIVE.
when I am starting hive cli it is working fine but when I am trying to start hiveserver2 it is not saying anything just hangs.

```
Mohit.mangal@Mohit-mangal-PC:~$ hiveserver2

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.1-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

It stays hanged then. Says nothing. Please help.

Comment: Did you ever heard about the concept of **service** i.e. a process that runs **in the background** and **waits** for client process to connect, while **logging to files** because a process in the background has no console?

Comment: Did you try to open another console and check whether HiveServe2 was listening on port 10000? E.g. `netstat -p --tcp --listening`?

Comment: Did you try to find the HS2 logs, probably somewhere in `/var/log`?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - I am unable to connect to hiveserver2 beeline console using jdbc on port 10000. it is saying connection refused.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - I am able to connect to hive cli and it is working well but unable to connect to beeline.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Actually It is showing following error when I am connection through beeline.

  Error: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: Mohit.mangal is not allowed to impersonate anonymous (state=,code=0)

can you help with it?

Comment: DID YOU TRY GOOGLE? That would have sent you to posts like this one: https://qnalist.com/questions/6266977/beeline-and-hiveserver2